# How to access wsdl xml format requests in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, soap, wsdl

We got wsdl description.how to access the wsdl in windows phone 7?we don't find which parameters need to send what is the response and what are the exact methods available in service?please tell me how to access wsdl in windows phone 7?

Answer (score 0):

You should use "Add service reference" on visual studio, check this [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx) for more info

It automatically generate all the stubs and data classes that you need from a wsdl contract.